# Should we have a [flying-wing] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

As the title asks, should we have a tag for questions about flying wing aircraft?

A [simple search for "flying wing"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=flying%20wing) on the main site brings up over 900 results.

If yes, should we also consider potential synonyms like [tailless]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea to me. I could definitely imagine someone thinking "I want to learn more about flying wings" or "I want to answer some questions about flying wings."

(Heck, *I* want to learn more about flying wings. How does that even work?)

But I also feel like it'd make more sense to have the tag be called [tailless](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailless) or [tailless-aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailless-aircraft) instead of [flying-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying-wing). If we created [flying-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying-wing), we wouldn't have a tag we could apply to other tailless aircraft; but if we created [tailless](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailless), we could apply that tag to flying wings.

The tag description could be something like: *Any aircraft that doesn't have a horizontal stabilizer or any other horizontal surface besides its main wing.*

Answer (score 2):

A few observations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:List_of_tailless_aircraft#Merger_proposal says:

- Flying wings are a proper subset of tailless (only one horizontal
  airfoil) aircraft.
- Flying wing is the more popular term.

Google books ngram viewer says that tailless is hundreds of times more common,
but that must refer to animals.  "Flying wing" has a blip from 1939 to 1945.

Comment: During World War II, a "wing of fighters" was the aircraft version of a "flock of crows".

Comment: Even today a wing can be a collection of squadrons.  http://www.rcaf-arc.forces.gc.ca/en/8-wing/index.page

Answer (score 1):

Does the existing [blended-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blended-wing) count? Perhaps we should discuss its related terms: What should the master term be? And shall we include the terms @TannerSwett mentioned in [their response](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3857/14897) as more synonyms to whichever master term we decide on?

Comment: A `blended-wing` airplane aka Blended Wing Body might have a tail.  A tailless airplane might not be a BWB.  The terms are independent, Northrop's famous types notwithstanding.